Can $5$ persons in an $8$ft $\times$ $8$ft room obey the $6$ft social distancing rule?
The context of this problem may be dated.

Suppose you have five persons in an $8$ ft $\times$ $8$ ft square room. Is it possible to spread them out so that there is no violation of a $6$ ft social distancing rule?


This is basically packing circles into a square: can five circles of radius $r=3$ be packed into a square of side length $8+2r=14$, or five unit circles into a square of side length $14/3=4.666\ldots$?  The best packing is into a square of side $2+2\sqrt{2}=4.828\ldots$.  So the answer is no.

@mjqxxxx there is a crucial difference between packing circles and OP's problem you've overlooked. You can place people on walls, but you cannot do the same with the centers of the circles.

@NinadMunshi correct, which is why the extra $2r$ needed to be added to the original side length of $8$.  The centers are in the square of size $8$ iff the entire circles are in the square of size $8+2r$.

The usage of circles and all may be overkill, I seems obvious that the optimal distancing in this particular case is $1$ people in each corner and $1$ in the center of the room and as in Marc Reyes answer, the half diagonal of the room is too small.

You've shown that positioning four people in the corners and the fifth at the center does not work. But proving that one possible solution does not work is not proof that nothing works.

Divide the 8x8 square into four 4x4 squares. Given the Pigeonhole Principle, there is at least one sub-square that has two persons inside that square. The longest line segment inside that square is its diagonal. But the length of that diagonal is √32 < 6.Answer, No, it is not possible.

Pigeonholing wins again!
